# How to remove listview all items

Tags: android, listview, adapter

In my app, if you click on a button then i want to remove all the listview items.
Here, i am using the base adapter for adding the items to the list view.

How can i remove the listview items dynamically.

Comment: dynamically pass getcount, to clear pass zero as getcount

Comment: listview.setAdapter(null);

Comment: Thank you Abhi, that really helped. Overriding the getCount method ....

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Call `setListAdapter()` again. This time with an empty ArrayList.

Comment: Here if you click on the button old data listview item will be removed after that new items will be added to the list view. is it possible with this?

Comment: Yes, you can call setListAdaptor() with new data as needed.

Comment: Calling setListAdapter() with a new Adapter object would be expensive. Just remove all the items in the adapter using clear() and add the new data to existing Adapter object using add()/addAll() and call notifyDatasetChanged().

Answer (score 26):

`ListView` operates based on the underlying data in the `Adapter`. In order to clear the `ListView` you need to do two things:

1. Clear the data that you set from adapter.
2. Refresh the view by calling `notifyDataSetChanged`

For example, see the skeleton of `SampleAdapter` below that extends the `BaseAdapter`

```
public class SampleAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    ArrayList<String> data;

    public SampleAdapter() {
        this.data = new ArrayList<String>();
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return data.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // your View
        return null;
    }
}
```

Here you have the `ArrayList<String> data` as the data for your Adapter. While you might not necessary use ArrayList, you will have something similar in your code to represent the data in your ListView

Next you provide a method to clear this data, the implementation of this method is to clear the underlying data structure

```
public void clearData() {
    // clear the data
    data.clear();
}
```

If you are using any subclass of [Collection](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Collection.html), they will have [clear()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Collection.html#clear%28%29) method that you could use as above.

Once you have this method, you want to call `clearData` and `notifyDataSetChanged` on your `onClick` thus the code for `onClick` will look something like:

```
// listView is your instance of your ListView
SampleAdapter sampleAdapter = (SampleAdapter)listView.getAdapter();
sampleAdapter.clearData();

// refresh the View
sampleAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Answer (score 10):

if you used List object and passed to the adapter you can remove the value from the List object and than call the notifyDataSetChanged() using adapter object.

for e.g.

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayAdapter adapter;


adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(DeleteManyTask.this, 
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            (String[])list.toArray(new String[0]));

listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
listview.setAdapter(adapter);

listview.setAdapter(listAdapter);
```

for remove do this way

```
list.remove(index); //or
list.clear();
adpater.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

or without list object remove item from list.

```
adapter.clear();
adpater.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: i am using the base adapter. so i don't have clear() metthod. how to remove it?

Answer (score 8):

You can only use

```
 lv.setAdapter(null);
```

Answer (score 5):

You can do this:

```
listView.setAdapter(null);
```

Answer (score 4):

I used this statement and it worked for me:

```
   setListAdapter(null)
```

This one calls a default constructor that does nothing in a class extends BaseAdapter.

Comment: this will break android 2.1

Answer (score 3):

I just clean the arraylist , try values.clear();

```
values = new ArrayList<String>();
values.clear();

ArrayAdapter <String> adapter;
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list,android.R.id.text1, values); 
lista.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the data from the `adapter` and call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

Comment: how to remove the data from the adpater?

Comment: while declaring adapter you would have passed values in some form...remove the value from there....

Comment: That is the question. How to remove the items from the adapter.

Answer (score 0):

use any one of the bellow options which suites your requirement

```
listview.removeViews(1,listview.getChildCount());
```

or

```
listview.removeViewInLayout(your view);
```

Answer (score 0):

An other approach after trying the solutions below. When you need it clear, just initialise your list to new clear new list.

```
List<ModelData> dataLists = new ArrayList<>();
                RaporAdapter adapter = new RaporAdapter(AyrintiliRapor.this, dataLists);
                listview.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Or set visibility to Gone / Invisible up to need

```
img_pdf.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

Answer (score 0):

For me worked this way:

```
private ListView yourListViewName;
private List<YourClassName> yourListName;

  ...

yourListName = new ArrayList<>();
yourAdapterName = new yourAdapterName(this, R.layout.your_layout_name, yourListName);

  ...

if (yourAdapterName.getCount() > 0) {
   yourAdapterName.clear();
   yourAdapterName.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

yourAdapterName.add(new YourClassName(yourParameter1, yourParameter2, ...));
yourListViewName.setAdapter(yourAdapterName);
```

Answer (score 0):

//very simple 
adapter.clear();