# How to clear a listFragments ArrayAdapter (subcalss) and display emptyView

Tags: java, android, android-arrayadapter

I am working on a basic file manager and would like to know how i can clear an ArrayAdapter subclass (namely my coustom FileListAdapter) and still get the emptyView to display. here is my current way of making the ArrayAdapter if there are no files:

```
if(selectedFile.listFiles() == null){
    mAdapter = new FileListAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.file_item_layout, new File[0]);
    mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

This is the emptyView

`mListView.setEmptyView(getActivity().findViewById(android.R.id.empty));
 setEmptyText("Empty folder");`

Here is my coustom adapter:

```
public class FileListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<File> {

private File[] folderContents;
private LayoutInflater inflater;

public FileListAdapter(Context context, int resource, File[] fileList) {
    super(context, resource, fileList);
    folderContents = fileList;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View itemView = convertView;
    if(itemView == null){
        itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.file_item_layout, parent, false);
    }

    //find the file
    File currentFile = folderContents[position];

    //fill the view
    ImageView iconImage = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.file_icon);
    iconImage.setImageResource(FileType.getTypeImage(FileType.parseType(currentFile)));

    String fileName = currentFile.getName();
    TextView fileNameText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.file_name);
    fileNameText.setText(fileName);

    String fileType = FileType.parse(currentFile);
    TextView fileTypeText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.file_type);
    fileTypeText.setText(fileType);

    String fileSizeText;

    if(!currentFile.isDirectory()){
        long fileSize = currentFile.length();
        if(fileSize < 1024){
            fileSizeText = fileSize + " Bytes";
        } else if(fileSize >= 1024 && fileSize < 1048576){
            //fileSizeText = (fileSize/1024) + "KB";
            fileSizeText = String.format("%.2f KB", (float)(fileSize/1024.0));
        } else if(fileSize >= 1048576 && fileSize < 1073741824){
            //fileSizeText = (fileSize/1048576) + "MB";
            fileSizeText = String.format("%.2f MB", (float)(fileSize/1048576.0));
        } else {
            //fileSizeText = (fileSize/1073741824) + "GB";
            fileSizeText = String.format("%.2f GB", (float)(fileSize/1073741824.0));
        }
    }
    else{
        File[] dirContents = currentFile.listFiles();
        if(dirContents == null){
            fileSizeText = "N/A";
        } else {
            if(dirContents.length == 1){
                fileSizeText ="1 item";
            }
            else{
                fileSizeText = dirContents.length + " items";
            }
        }
    }
    TextView fileSizeTextView = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.file_size);
    fileSizeTextView.setText(fileSizeText);

    Date lastModifiedDate = new Date(currentFile.lastModified());
    String lastModifiedText = "<" +lastModifiedDate.getMonth() + "/" + lastModifiedDate.getDate() + "/" + (lastModifiedDate.getYear() + 1900) + ">";
    TextView lastModifiedDateText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.last_modified);
    lastModifiedDateText.setText(lastModifiedText);

    return itemView;
}
```

}

Here is the layout for lists (replace listview with gridview to get the other one)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" tools:context="com.pcgeekbrain.madfiles.FileViewFragment">

<ListView android:id="@android:id/list" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<TextView android:id="@android:id/empty" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:gravity="center" />

</FrameLayout>
```

what I get is a blank screen. How can I make the emptyView appear when there is no files in the folder?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can check :    mAdapter .add(null); or
    mAdapter = new FileListAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.file_item_layout, null);

Comment: null causes app to crash

Comment: you can create Model(is File[] of you) ,after mAdapter .add(new Model());

Comment: Have you used ListFragment?

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE 3**

Put this on your adapter

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return folderContents.length;
}
```

**UPDATE 2**

```
// method setEmptyView on ListView

@android.view.RemotableViewMethod
public void setEmptyView(View emptyView) {
    mEmptyView = emptyView;

    // If not explicitly specified this view is important for accessibility.
    if (emptyView != null
            && emptyView.getImportantForAccessibility() == IMPORTANT_FOR_ACCESSIBILITY_AUTO) {
        emptyView.setImportantForAccessibility(IMPORTANT_FOR_ACCESSIBILITY_YES);
    }

    final T adapter = getAdapter();
    final boolean empty = ((adapter == null) || adapter.isEmpty()); // <- see that
    updateEmptyStatus(empty);
}

// meanwhile, on ArrayAdapter...
// adapter.isEmpty returns getCount!

public boolean isEmpty() {
    return getCount() == 0;
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

Try implement this on your `FileListAdapter`:

```
public void removeAll() {
    this.folderContents = new File[]{};
}
```

And turn empty like this:

```
adapterInstance.removeAll();
adapterInstance.notifyDataChanged();
```

---

You need remove the itens ans call `notifyDataChanged()`. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7401022/2649418) answer for more details.

Comment: you ever considered that your "emptyView" may not be appearing? sometimes I put my "listView" with height "match_parent" and this hide the "emptyView". Can you check this?

Comment: the fragments views were generated with match parent.

Comment: try make the emptyView appear without the listView (you must change id to this test)

Comment: You do not put a text! Try add `android:text="lorem ipsum"` on textView please.

Comment: so, now is working? to show on center use `layout_gravity='center'` or change `framelayout` to `relative` ;)

Comment: I only want to see it when it is empty. Not all the time

Comment: the ListView has itens and emptView is Visible?

Answer (score 0):

search for your empty view in fragment like below

```
 @Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    ListView listView = (ListView)view.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    listView.setEmptyView(view.findViewById(android.R.id.empty));

    ArrayAdapter<Session> adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<Session>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, 
            android.R.id.text1, MainController.getInstanz().getItems());
    listView.setAdapter(adapter1);
}
```

Comment: No change. still gives me blank screen

Comment: Are you extending ListFragment? Have you used any custom layout for the fragment?

Comment: No i am not and no, i just did a new fragment(list) in android studio

Comment: post your layout containing listview and the empty view.

Comment: Please do check above

Comment: i think you are searching for the empty view in activity.instead you should be searching for the empty view in onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) callback. i have shown it in my edited answer.Hope it helps.

Comment: no, it was not i was doing. BTW. I have worked around the problem and am now facing a similar but different issue. Thanks for trying to help me though.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that there are many places where its activity / fragment may be having trouble, so I'm pasting an example of how it should be implemented an adapter to "listView" and "emptyView"

**HomeActivity.java**

```
package br.com.luiskaufmannsilva.examplefilemanager;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


public class HomeActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);


        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.content, new FileListFragment())
                .commit();
    }




}
```

**FileListFragment.java**

```
package br.com.luiskaufmannsilva.examplefilemanager;


import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.File;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class FileListFragment extends Fragment {


    private ListView listView = null;
    private FileListAdapter adapter = null;

    public FileListFragment() {}


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_file_list, container, false);

        listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.list);

        listView.setEmptyView(view.findViewById(android.R.id.empty));

        final File file = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        adapter = new FileListAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), file.listFiles());

        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        new Handler()
                .postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        adapter.clear();
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                        new Handler()
                                .postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                        adapter.setFiles(file.listFiles());
                                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                    }
                                }, 5 * 1000);


                    }
                }, 5 * 1000);

        return view;
    }


    class FileListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<File>{

        private LayoutInflater inflater;
        private File[] files;

        public FileListAdapter(Context context, File[] objects) {
            super(context, R.layout.file_item, objects);
            this.files = objects;
            this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        }

        public void setFiles(File[] files) {
            this.files = files;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return files.length;
        }

        @Override
        public void clear() {
            files = new File[]{};
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.file_item, parent, false);

            //find the file
            File currentFile = files[position];

            //fill the view
            ImageView iconImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.file_icon);
            iconImage.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher); // do not

            TextView fileNameView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.file_name);
            fileNameView.setText(currentFile.getName());

            return convertView;
        }
    }

}
```

**activity_home.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".HomeActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"></LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**fragment_file_list.xml**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="br.com.luiskaufmannsilva.examplefilemanager.FileListFragment">

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"></ListView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@android:id/empty"
        android:text="No itens"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</FrameLayout>
```

**file_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/file_icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:textColor="#ff000000"
        android:id="@+id/file_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="br.com.luiskaufmannsilva.examplefilemanager" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".HomeActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

The above example produces this:

*initial:*
[image: initial]

*past five seconds*
[image: after 5 seconds]

*past five seconds again*
[image: after 5 seconds again]

Comment: what is with the handler?

Comment: is not importante, i use it only to display after 5 seconds, this [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) explain what is it.

Comment: No it does not do that. now all the text is suddenly white, it seams like there is another fragment on top of it. and the text still shows all the time. Thank you for breaking my app.

Comment: also if i go into a folder with the usable fragment the top one stays there. why is the text white?